# Batch File to Open Home Page, Pause, Then Run Another Command

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that runs fine, but it requires me to already have the web browser open. The batch file opens a URL that enters my user name and password. Again - all that works perfect. But I really would love to figure out how to run the same batch file that will first open my home page, pause, then run my normal script.

Here is my original batch file which runs fine (just need to already have the browser open):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
set timeout=5
start "" https://website.com/
timeout %timeout%
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "username"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "password"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Here is my attempt to open my home page followed by my original script:

```
@echo off
Start "" https://homepage.com/

@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
set timeout=5
start "" https://website.com/
timeout %timeout%
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "username"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "password"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Thanks to different Stack Overflow solutions, I was able to figure out how to run my script and it I am happy with it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to run back to back scripts in the same file. I think I need to add something after the second line and before the second @echo off. Any suggestions?

Comment: You use the same file for batch and jscript, which have complete different command sets. So your file should start with a command that tells jscript to ignore a part of it while also being a valid command for batch. This starting line is `@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then`, which is a valid batch syntax and tells jscript the beginning of a comment section, ending with `@end`. everything batch-related has to be within those lines and must end in `goto :eof`. so the batch interpreter does not execute the following jscript part.

Comment: So remove the first two lines and put the `start` command (which is batch) after the `@echo off` (within the batch-part).

Comment: Thank you @Stephan It works, but I had to change the time out to 10 seconds because the home page takes a little longer to load. After that, it goes to the second part which continues to work like a charm!!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Stephan for the quick answer! This is the final code:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
Start "" https://homepage.com/
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
set timeout=10
start "" https://website.com/
timeout %timeout%
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "username"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "password"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```